# Cannot start evince in root with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: root, evince

Evince can be opened in root in Ubuntu 14.04. With Ubuntu 16.04, I can open evince with a non-root user but in root, I get

```
# evince file.pdf
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: Permission denied
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

The same thing applies for several other utilities such as `pdftk`:

```
pdftk file.pdf cat 1down output file2.pdf
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
1
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Comment: So what’s the purpose of the question here if you reported it as a bug?

Comment: "Evince can be opened in root in Ubuntu 14.04" ... and that is a good thing so be happy! If you want to use root use another operating system.

Comment: Rinzwind - he asked for help, not for your opinion. Your opinion is not relevant to the matter. Unfortunately I have encountered the same issue and I do not know why or where ubuntu blocks the superuser so maliciously.